# What are the limitations of an app developed for Salesforce?

Tags: appexchange, java, developer-console, app, developer

I am totally new to Salesforce app development and I was wondering about the limitations of the entire framework if there are any. Myself and a friend of mine have developed in C# and Java an API for data mining and would like to find out if it would be possible to port that into Salesforce. I read a few things talking about limitations within the Salesforce framework and I am wondering if that is the case. The API we have developed requires decent processing power and memory so any limitations might be a showstopper.

Comment: I recommend you look at the [Force.com Fundamentals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/) and the [Quick Limits Ref Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/) along with other docs from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs to learn about SF's multi-tennant metadata driven architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many built in limitations related to individual transactions/requests - see [Understanding Execution Governors and Limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm). These limits are high enough for typical interactive applications but may not be for the processing you have in mind. If it is OK that results are available later (asynchronously) [batch Apex](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) can be used to break the work up into many separate transactions and so stay within the limits.

There are also programming language limitations and available API limitations as the Apex language and the APIs it makes available are proprietary. So, for example, there is no ability to manipulate binary data and there are few streaming APIs to help process large volumes of data.

If you have complex code to debug, the debugging mechanisms are presently poor compared to those available for the languages you mention which will slow down development.

But I suggest the best way to find out if there are showstoppers or not is to go ahead and try to port a small part of your code.